# Electric guitar for soft sound?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

What electric guitar could make this kind of sounds ?

Will "Squier Classic Vibe Telecaster '50s - Vintage Blonde" be ok for me ?
I'm a noob and don't know nothing about electric guitars..
I'm really into this soft quiet music, I'm not a fan of that loud rock guitar sound and doing fancy solos..

Comment: The word you're looking for is "clean", not soft. :) Clean electric guitar sound.

Comment: If it's any help, this is almost certainly fingerstyle. Using the pads of the players fingers, not a pick. That reduces the amount of 'hard edges' in the sound.

Comment: No guitar, and possibly any guitar.  It depends as much on the amp and set up.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with almost any electric guitar. That's what an electric guitar sounds like when you don't add any effects.

You'll want to look for an amplifier that has a "clean channel", i.e. one without effects.

Comment: There's no distortion, but I think there's some reverb....

Answer (score 3):

This is virtually asking for gear recommendations - which is offside for this site. However, it has more of the sound of an acoustic or electro-acoustic guitar than a solid electric.

Most guitars heard on tracks have some sort of effects used on them, whereas this has maybe a little reverb and that's it. The sound of any guitar being played is contributed to by far more than merely the guitar itself. The amp, the recording, and of course the player and his techniques. Just buying a guitar that was used on xyz recording to make abc sound in no way guarantees that you will be able to produce the same sound, either in your bedroom or on a huge stage.

Comment: You forgot the cable. No, I am not talking about "expensive cables sounding better". It's just that the cable some capacitance (among other parameters) and this capacitance forms a filter circuit which can modify the sound of some pickups noticeably. A few people apparently don't like to play their guitar over short cables because they perceive that as "too bright" (and tone controls cut into the sound too much for their taste). Whatever, here's one of many demo videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmiTy0TZ3-M

Comment: @Klaws - duly noted. Yes, it's basically the missing link in the answer, and, yes, important too! Unless, of course, one goes wireless...

Answer (score 1):

In general, the quality of a guitar (wood selection, construction tolerances, pickups) will be more important to creating a good clean sound than if there are a bunch of effects applied. Not saying a Squier can't do it, but e.g. something made out of plywood would not be ideal.

Comment: Let's retire the tone wood myth for solid-body electric guitars: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V76yWZ3-OuM